# QThread signal START

Tags: c++, qt5

Добрый день! 
Не могу найти как запустить QThread из другого класса.

```
class some;
class some2;

thread1 = new QThread;
connect(thread1, &QThread::started, some, &SomeClass::Go);
connect(some, &SomeClass::s_stop, thread1, &QThread::quit);
```

И вот теперь самое главное, я хочу запускать поток по сигналу.

```
connect(some2, &SomeClass2::s_start, thread1, &QThread::start);
```

Такая вот запись не работает, пишет что слишком мало аргументов у сигнала.
Если написать thread1-> start все работает. Но, мне нужно именно по сигналу. Возможно ли так сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
connect(some2, &SomeClass2::s_start, thread1, QThread::start);
```

Исправьте на

```
connect(some2, &SomeClass2::s_start, thread1, &QThread::start);
```

В этой строке тоже

```
connect(thread1, QThread::started, some, &SomeClass::Go);
```

на

```
connect(thread1, &QThread::started, some, &SomeClass::Go);
```

Если посмотреть внимательней, то сигнатура метода QThread::start выглядит так:

```
void start(QThread::Priority);
```

Соответственно и Ваш сигнал должен иметь аналогичную сигнатуру:

```
void s_start(QThread::Priority);
```

Comment: Исправил опечатки

Comment: Добавить сигнатуру метода SomeClass2::s_start в описание вопроса

Comment: Сигнал void s_start(), я не знаю что туда писать.

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо больше! То что нужно.